# Conexión Server Cliente con Hilos en Java

Tags: java, mysql, hilos

Estoy intentando hacer un "proyecto" de recepciones de hotel con un Servidor que se mantendría siempre encendido y va recibiendo Clientes y creando Hilos de estos. Mi duda viene a la hora de acceder a una BD mySQL que he creado para los hoteles, que entiendo deberían hacerlo los Hilos, con los métodos de acceso en estos, siendo que el servidor sólo se encarga de crear los Hilos, pero la verdad es que tengo el tema de los Threads un poco verdes.

He hecho chats TCP siguiendo este modelo antes, pero como no tenían acceso a BD se me hacían un poco más sencillos, pero cuando lo junto con SQL no sé por dónde cogerlo.

También sé que, al iniciar el Servidor de mi proyecto, he de crear un HiloServidor, por así llamarlo, que sea el que va aceptando clientes y creando hilos de estos, y entiendo que los métodos de acceso a la BD están en estos "HilosCliente", pero hasta ahí es dónde puedo sacar, puesto que no sé llevarlo a cabo de la teoría a la práctica.

¿Alguien sabría ayudarme y explicarme el tema un poco?

Comment: Sinceramente es una pregunta bastante amplia. Muchos conectores para bases de datos permiten realizar una sola conexión y a la hora de realizar transacciones crean sesiones temporales, para cada hilo. Es más, algunas tienen incluso un parámetro para hacer la conexión "Thread safe" y evitar problemas de incongruencia.

Comment: Soy plenamente consciente de que es muy amplio, pero tampoco sé explicarme mejor y es un tema que me lleva de cabeza desde hace ya varios días y no consigo avanzar en él

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La pregunta es bastante amplia, pero como lo que buscas es más indicaciones que código, intentaré aportar algo:

Te recomiendo usar un "pool de conexiones" que gestione la comunicación con la base de datos, de ese modo no tendrás problemas con los hilos accediendo simultáneamente. En cualquier servidor J2EE se suele usar esta estrategia, ya que cada petición es gestionada por un thread distinto. No sé que librerías o *frameworks* usas, pero existen ya bastantes librerías que simplemente con recibir la configuración de la base de datos se encargan de gestionar todo: Tu código se limitaría a pedir conexiones cuando hiciera falta.